# or where query does not returns results while separate queries returns results

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

this SQL query returns some results:

```sql
select
  "titres".*
from
  "titres"
  inner join "titres_titulaires" as "titulaires_join" on "titulaires_join"."titre_etape_id" = "titres"."titulaires_titre_etape_id"
  inner join "entreprises" as "titulaires" on "titulaires_join"."entreprise_id" = "titulaires"."id"
where
  ("titulaires"."nom" like '%sma%')
```

I expect this query to return at least the same results:

```sql
select
  "titres".*
from
  "titres"
  inner join "titres_titulaires" as "titulaires_join" on "titulaires_join"."titre_etape_id" = "titres"."titulaires_titre_etape_id"
  inner join "entreprises" as "titulaires" on "titulaires_join"."entreprise_id" = "titulaires"."id"
  inner join "titres_amodiataires" as "amodiataires_join" on "amodiataires_join"."titre_etape_id" = "titres"."amodiataires_titre_etape_id"
  inner join "entreprises" as "amodiataires" on "amodiataires_join"."entreprise_id" = "amodiataires"."id"
where
  (
    "titulaires"."nom" like '%sma%'
    or "amodiataires"."nom" like '%sma%'
  )
```

but it returns an empty array.

what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The join conditions do not match on the new tables.

Comment: which conditions?

Comment: change all your INNER joins to LEFT join and it will work. The problem is that for the titre(s) your are looking for , none have BOTH a titulaire and an amoditaire, and thus all results are filtered out by the INNER joins. Your query is easier to understand for a french-speaker ;-)

Comment: should I change ALL the joins to left joins, or just the last two like suggested in the answer below. What is the difference?

Comment: you can keep the answer below ONLY if for ALL titres you have ALWAYS a titulaire, and MAYBE an amanditaire. If for some titres, you have no titulaire, your results will be filtered.

Comment: *should I change ALL the joins...* you tell us. The correct answer is *your* desired result.

Comment: *Why* do you expect it? The current answer to your question is just, because that's how joins work. What do you expect us to be able to tell you other than that? Explain with justification via reference to an authoritative definition. Then we can say where you are wrong. PS Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use left join instead inner join for last 2joins

```
select
  "titres".*
from
  "titres"
  inner join "titres_titulaires" as "titulaires_join" on "titulaires_join"."titre_etape_id" = "titres"."titulaires_titre_etape_id"
  inner join "entreprises" as "titulaires" on "titulaires_join"."entreprise_id" = "titulaires"."id"
  left join "titres_amodiataires" as "amodiataires_join" on "amodiataires_join"."titre_etape_id" = "titres"."amodiataires_titre_etape_id"
  left join "entreprises" as "amodiataires" on "amodiataires_join"."entreprise_id" = "amodiataires"."id"
where
  (
    "titulaires"."nom" like '%sma%'
    or "amodiataires"."nom" like '%sma%'
  )
```

Comment: Although your answer might be correct it would be nice to explain him WHY.

Comment: @ThomasG with out seeing sample output its tough to say it will not work and change for all join so it depends but fo r the problwm that op said that 1st query return something but 2nd not in that case it will work

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain why this can happen.

Let's imagine that there is not a single row in `titres_amodiataires` that matches a row in `titres`, i.e., no two rows satisfy `titres_amodiataires.titre_etape_id = titres.amodiataires_titre_etape_id`.

Then the result of the `JOIN`s will be empty, and applying the additional filters in the `WHERE` condition won't make it any less empty.